# C# INSERT TO access database creates 2 database entries rather than 1

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I have created a C# program to insert data into an Access database, with some well known code.

Every time I run the code I get two entries in the database

```
namespace Quotes
{
public partial class QuotesForm : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection quotescon;
    private OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand();
    private string connect = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=H:\Quotes.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";

    public QuotesForm()
    {
        quotescon = new OleDbConnection(connect);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int quote = Convert.ToInt32(txtb_Quotenumber.Text);
        quotescon.Open();
        oledbcmd.Connection = quotescon;
        oledbcmd.CommandText = "insert into table1 ([Quote number], Account, Made, Approved) values ('" + quote + "','" + this.txtb_name.Text + "','" + this.date_created.Text + "','" + this.comboBox1.Text +"');";
        oledbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int temp = oledbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if(temp > 0)
        {
            txtb_Quotenumber.Text = null;
            txtb_name.Text = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Entry has been Successfuly Added to Database","Data Added",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data entry has not been added Successfuly, Please try again", "Failed To add Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        quotescon.Close();

    }
```

Comment: You are calling `oledbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` twice so it is doing 2 inserts.

Comment: It's the kind of question which a simple debuging will solve.

Answer (score 5):

Because you execute your command twice.

One with

```
oledbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And another with

```
int temp = oledbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Just delete the first one.

From [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **Executes** a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns
>   the number of rows affected.

But more important, you should **always** use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

And use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`.

```
using(OleDbConnection quotescon = new OleDbConnection(connect))
using(OleDbCommand oledbcmd= con.CreateCommand())
{
    oledbcmd.CommandText = @"insert into table1 ([Quote number], Account, Made, Approved)
                            values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    oledbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", quote);
    oledbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account", this.txtb_name.Text);
    oledbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@made", this.date_created.Text);
    oledbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@approved", this.comboBox1.Text);
    int temp = oledbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if(temp > 0)
    {
        txtb_Quotenumber.Text = null;
        txtb_name.Text = null;
        MessageBox.Show("Entry has been Successfuly Added to Database","Data Added",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data entry has not been added Successfuly, Please try again", "Failed To add Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are executing the query twice with

```
oledbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int temp = oledbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```